# Update context api value from child components reactjs

Tags: reactjs

just Stuck in this Problem for a few a days. It Goes like this:I have  given permissions for user  for  module  in app.js and passed permissions to module via context api .Once i Provide this Permission value to that module as True and run the app.js component it works perfectly But when i go the Permission component and changes the Checkbox values as need then its doesn't instantly on that module unless i reload  the whole app.js component so it provide that values to the module and worked as it Is.How can i update Permission value from Permission component so i didn't have to reload whole app.js or reload the whole component?

```
  ** App.js**
        import UserAuthenticationContext from "./contexts/UserAuthenticationContext";
        function app(){
         const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState(); 
         const [per, setPer] = useState(); 
     useEffect(() => {
       getPermissions();
      },[])
     const getPermissions = () => {
        axios .get(`${config.APP_CONFIG}/UserPermission`)
          .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.status_code === 200) {
              setPermissions(res.data.msg)
            } else {
              toast.error("Error Loading Permission");
              setPermissions([]);
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            toast.error("cannot fetch Permission");
            //setPermissions([]);
          });
      };
      //return permissions=    [{"id":1,"module_name":"Product","role":"users","create":1,"delete":1,"rea//d":1,"write": 1},]
        
 Context Api        
   <UserAuthenticationContext.Provider value={{ permissions : permissions,  }} >
```

**Permission  component**

```
     function Permissions (){
    const [perm, setPerm] = useState(); 
    
    return (
     //4 checkbox i.e containing Read,write,delete operation 
    <tr>
    <th>Module name></th>
    <th>Create</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Update</th>
    <th>Read</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      {pers.map((cell, index) => (
     <tr key={index}>
      <td>{cell.moduleName}</td>
      <td> {getCheckBox(index, 'create',cell.id)}</td>
    and so on
```

Comment: Did you export this `const [perm, setPerm] = useState();` from your `Context`?

Comment: @Nick Vu Can you 
illustrate more ?

Comment: You can add a HOC for your Context (https://medium.com/@niwaa/simple-and-reusable-react-context-api-example-hoc-e1e50c0390ec) and after that, whenever you update `perm` with `setPerm`, all your components use your context will get updated too.